# How to Upgrade a newly added property in all existing nodes?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, umbraco

We are managing an umbraco site  which has over 2000 nodes .We have   recently added a new property in one of our master document type,since it is a new property the existing nodes doesn't have the property value .We have to update the value of that property in  each node   before deploying the new changes.It is very difficult to update the values manually since it takes a lot of time.What  we are planning is  to use a one time upgrade aspx page or user control to accomplish this job. has anyone ever been into this kind of a situation ?how to make a one time upgrade page ? Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fairly sure that this isn't in the core and that there hasn't been a package created for exactly this purpose.  But it's pretty simple to create a macro containing a razor (cshtml) script that updates a single property for all the descendants of a particular node:

Something like (just from memory of the Level 2 course):

```
var nodes = @Model.DescendantsOrSelf(-1); //-1 is the root node
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
  Document doc = new Document(node.Id);
  doc.getProperty("yourProperty").Value = "xxx"; // the getProperty looks wrong, I know
  doc.Publish(new User(0));  //User 0 is the admin user
  umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(doc.Id);
}
```

This great package http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/content-maintenance-dashboard-package does mass updating, but last time I checked it didn't update single fields - but it might do by now.

Comment: This functionality already exists if you see my post below. I use it so often I keep meaning to develop a package to provide easier access to the dialog.

Comment: @ProNotion You answer does not update a property on all nodes - read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought doing a republish of the xml cache should do this if you go to the following url:

/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

Comment: I think the OP is asking a different question.  That link republishes all nodes - the OP wants to know how to change a single value on all nodes and then publish.